# Cargar datos en un modal ajax y Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

mi inconveniente es al tratar de mostrar informaciôn en un modal, me aparece en blanco, adjunto codigo, les agradezco tomen tiempo de verlo y alguna sugerencia

Modelo

```
    public function get_infoBureau($idBureau)
{
    $data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/silose/localisations/exact/id_bureau/'.$idBureau);
    return json_decode($data);

}
```

Controlador
En la funcion primero cargo una imagen y en esa misma vista quisiera pasar el resultado con el modal cuando da clic en la imagen(supongo que aqui estâ el error)

```
public function view_plan($nomSite, $etage)
{
    $id_selected = $this->input->post("id_select");
    $data = [
        'view' => 'plan_detail',
        'etage' => $etage,
        'typeBureau' => $this->plan_model->get_typeBureau(),
        'site' => $nomSite,
        'id' => $this->plan_model->get_infoBureau($id_selected)
    ];


    $this->load->view("master", $data);

}
```

Js

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/plan/view_plan/' + nomSite + "/" + etage ,
    data: 'id_select=' + id,
    success: function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                $("#modal").modal('show');

            }
        ), 2000

    }
```

En la vista dentro del modal paso lo sig:

```
    <?php if (is_array($id)) {
                        foreach ($id as $info) { ?>
                            <p> <?php echo
                                $info->tel_professionnel,
                                $info->personne->prenom,
                                $info->personne->nom_usage ?></p>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas el HTML de la modal en la Vista?

Comment: Date cuenta que `$("#modal").modal('show');` lo único que hace es hacer visible un *modal* que se encuentra cargado ya en la Vista. Por lo que al tratar de construirlo dinamicamente con unos datos pedidos por **AJAX** no vas a tener esos datos accesibles. Lo que tendrías  que hacer es cargar la modal con los datos vacíos y en el *success* de la llamada **AJAX** rellenarlos con Javascript (a partir del *data* que te devuelve el servidor) antes de hacer el `modal('show')`.

Comment: Gracias por reponder @phpMyGuel, con ajax estoy pasando el id (segun la imagen que seleccionen) a mi controlador para que el modelo  me devuelva los datos que quiero mostrar en el modal, al tratar usar el data antes del modal('show'), me vuelve a cargar la vista

Comment: Tienes ahí un error de concepto. Lo que se espera de una llamada *AJAX* es que esta te devuelva un conjunto de datos que poder usar para modificar la Vista, no el que te devuelva una Vista completa porque poco puedes hacer con ella. Voy a tratar de construirte un pequeño esquema orientativo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grandes rasgos deberías seguir una estructura parecida para poder modificar la Vista con datos provenientes del Controlador que además necesitan de datos provenientes de la Vista.

**Modelo:**

```
public function get_infoBureau($idBureau) {
    $data = file_get_contents('http://localhost/silose/localisations/exact/id_bureau/'.$idBureau);

    return json_decode($data);
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function view_plan($nomSite, $etage) {
    $id_selected = $this->input->post("id_select");
    $data = [
        'view' => 'plan_detail',
        'etage' => $etage,
        'typeBureau' => $this->plan_model->get_typeBureau(),
        'site' => $nomSite,
        'id' => $this->plan_model->get_infoBureau($id_selected)
    ];

    //Devolvemos a la vista una estructura de datos
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**JS que se llama desde la Vista:**

```
   //Esta función se debería llamar al cargar la modal, para rellenarla antes de
   //mostrarla
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/plan/view_plan/' + nomSite + "/" + etage ,
    data: 'id_select=' + id,
    success: function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
                //Antes de cargar la modal habría que recorrer la estructura
                ///de datos que recibes del Controlador para ir rellenando
                //la modal que se debería encontrar cargada previamente
                //en la vista
                $("#modal").modal('show');

            }
        ), 2000

    }
```

**Vista:**

> Aquí tendría que ir tu vista con el **HTML** de la modal incluído para
>   poder afectarlo con el resultado de la llamada **AJAX**.

Comment: muchas gracias por el ejemplo aunque no me quedq muy claro como recorrer los datos del controlador estoy tratando con for(var indice in data) {
     $("#modal").html(data[indice].value);
    }

Comment: Al obtener un string **JSON** del Controlador, tendrías que convertirlo primero a objeto para poder acceder a sus atributos (con `let json = JSON.parse(data)`). Así tendrías el objeto con el que acceder a cada dato con `json.view` o `json.typeBureau`.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.